# Collation wasn't advertised to any validator. version: polkadot-v0.9.36

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain

When i am start running my parachain i am getting this issue Collation wasn't advertised to any validator.
During this issue the parachain cannot produce and block also.

Please help me if you have something which can help me in this issue[image]

Comment: But your chains are working right?

Comment: No. for that time parachain cannot produce new blocks.

Comment: Can you provide as much information as possible about the changes you made to the code and the steps to reproduce it. In addition, please put effort in formulating your sentences :)

Comment: to replicate it you can run relaychain and parachain with version v0.9.36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it happened because of change in the command which i did for some use-case.

I was using below command:

```
./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
--rpc-methods=unsafe
--rpc-cors all
--ws-external
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
```

Instead of default command we get to start relay chain.

```
./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same error and to avoid this and to produce and finalize blocks on parachain you need to add the same account in your relay chain that you added in session keys of parachain and then register the paraid from that account only.

Comment: adding the parachain session keys to relaychain? that doesn't sound right